# ng2-pagination errors, angular2, angular-cli

Tags: angular, pagination

Trying two add ng-pagenation to a component in my angular-cli app 
keep getting errors that I cant diagnose please some one help

> node-version 4.4.5
>
> npm version 3.8.7
>
> angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.8

```
**// admin component**

import { Component, OnInit,ChangeDetectionStrategy }
from'@angular/core';
import {AdminService} from '../admin.service';
import {PaginatePipe,PaginationService, PaginationControlsCmp} from
```

'ng2-pagination';

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'app-admin',
templateUrl: 'admin.component.html',
styleUrls: ['admin.component.css'],
providers:[AdminService,PaginationService],
pipes:[PaginatePipe]

})

export class adminComponent implements OnInit {
public approvedPrayers;
public unApprovedPrayers;
public prayer_error:Boolean = false;
constructor(private adminService:AdminService) {}

ngOnInit() {
}}


**// index.html** 
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="/">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Prayerbox</title>
<base href="/">
**<script src="https://rawgit.com/michaelbromley/
ng2-pagination/master/dist/ng2-pagination-bundle.js"></script>**

{{#unless environment.production}}
<script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

{{/unless}}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>



{{#each scripts.polyfills}}
<script src="{{.}}"></script>
{{/each}}
<script>
  System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
    System.import('main');
  }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**// error**

```
    ng2-pagination-bundle.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not 
    defined(anonymous function) @ ng2-pagination-bundle.js:10
    zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error 
   (404 Not Found)loading http://localhost:4200/ng2-pagination/index.js
```

Comment: Can you try importing ng2-pagination scripts after polyfills in index.html

Comment: the only thing i did in system config was this                                                // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',
   'ng2-pagination',

Answer (score 0):

In system-config.ts remove the reference you added after rxjs.
Then add the following at the top of the same file.

```
/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'ng2-pagination': 'vendor/ng2-pagination' 
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
    'ng2-pagination':{
    format: 'cjs'
  }
};
```

In the angular-cli-build.js include a reference to ng2-paginiation

```
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      ...,
      'ng2-pagination/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
```

Also remove any references in the index.html

Comment: now it gives error     zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:4200/vendor/ng2-pagination 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Update angular-cli-build.js file to copy ng2-pagination in vendor npm

Comment: Ok will try it thanx guys

Answer (score 0):

Allans answer works, except you need to change:

```
'ng2-pagination/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
```

To:

```
'ng2-pagination/**/*'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The solutions of Matte and Allan didn't work for me completely but pointed me into the right direction.

Here's my solution:

**angular-cli-build.js**:

```
return new Angular2App(defaults, {
  vendorNpmFiles: [
    ...,
    'ng2-pagination/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  ]
});
```

**system-config.ts**:

```
/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  ...
  'ng2-pagination': 'vendor/ng2-pagination'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  ...
};

packages['ng2-pagination'] = {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index',
};
```

**Important**:
After editing angular-cli-build.js:

1. Stop the server
2. `ng build`
3. `ng serve`

Without the `ng build` the files were not copied into the dist/vendor directory.

**Differences to the other proposals:**

This doesn't find the index file because it's not in the dist directory:

```
'ng2-pagination/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
```

This finds more files than needed:

```
'ng2-pagination/**/*'
```

I did `packages['ng2-pagination'] = {...}` because I've filled the packages array before using a function that I don't want to touch.

But it works as well with `const packages: any = {'ng2-pagination':{...}}`.

However it was necessary to add `defaultExtension: 'js'` and `main: 'index'`.

Otherwise the browser didn't find the module.

Comment: This worked for me too, but instead of adding the `defaultExtension: 'js'` and `main: 'index'` in the packages, I just added the index file as a third party barrel: `const barrels:string[] = ... ,'ng2-pagination', ...`.